# Why is css width rule overriding the max-width rule?

Tags: css

Can someone please explain to me why the max-width rule is not being applied. My images are 600px wide and when I have the browser window at full width (1920px) the images are 955px. If I change the max-width rule from max-width: 100% to max-width: 600px everything works as expected and the images do not exceed there 600px natural width. The images are supposed to be responsive. When the browser changes size the images scale but should not grow past there natural width 600px. Why is max-width: 100% being overruled by width?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>HTML Test Ground</title>
            <style>
                body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                img {
                    display: block;
                    float: left;
                    margin-right: 10px;
                    width: calc( (100% - 10px) / 2 );
                    max-width: 100%;
                }
                img:last-of-type {
                    margin-right: 0;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img src="Images/warGamesSmall.jpg" alt="Do You Want To Play A Game?">
            <img src="Images/warGamesSmall.jpg" alt="Do You Want To Play A Game?">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want it to be always 100%. try with `min-width:100%`

Comment: it works as expected :http://jsfiddle.net/6m0a3tc7/

Comment: and without the `width` http://jsfiddle.net/yruve75c/

Comment: It may be me misinterpreting my instructor. He seems to say that setting the img max-width rule will not let the image grow past its natural size of 600px. Does the max-width rule relate to the image or its containing block (the body)? If it relates to the body element, I can see where I am going wrong.

Comment: The user agent is doing exactly as instructed -- image width is always half of the calculated parent element width minus 10 pixels, and never wider than the entire parent element width. That's what your rules say. When the window is 1920 pixels wide, the images should rightfully be rendered 955 pixels wide, and no maximum width violation occurs as it is no larger than 1920 pixels. You need to better describe the behavior you're expecting, preferably in your question.

Comment: "Natural size" does not figure into this. Used width of an element will never exceed the computed value of `max-width`. If you want an image to never be wider than 600 CSS pixels, then specify `max-width: 600px`. But keep in mind that it may be narrower than that, and that it is the computed value of width that applies ordinarily (when neither maximum nor minimum width constraints are violated).

Comment: @amn - Barring your last sentence, I thought your answer answered the question asked fine. The real question I think the OP is trying to ask though is "How do I restrict the width of an image to be just less than half the container width and no greater than its intrinsic width"

Comment: @M.Kennedy - Yes it relates to the image's containing block, which in your example is the body element. The `max-width` property never takes the image's intrinsic size into account, but the `width` property does if its value is `auto`, so I think you can achieve the effect you want by setting the width to auto, and the max-width to `calc( (100% - 10px) / 2 );`

Comment: @Alohci - Thanks, I thought that I may be misinterpreting my instructor. I thought that max-width referred to the value of the image itself 600px not the containing element. I assumed my code read as - set the image size to half of the view port width and never let the image grow larger than its natural width 600px. It make more sence now that I know that max-width refers to the body element and not the image itself. Many thanks.

Comment: To clarify: no, the value specified for `max-width` is the acceptable maximum width of the image element, not the containing element. The containing element *only* comes into play if the value is a *relative* width, like a percentage width. Meaning, `max-width: 600px` applied *to your image element* means "the maximum accepted width *of this [image] element* is 600 pixels", and, similarly, `max-width: 50%` element means "the maximum accepted width *of the image* is half of the width of its containing block". You've understood wrong. I am unsure how I can make this clearer, but I will try :)

Comment: @Alohci To answer the question "how do I restrict the width of an image to be just less than half the container width and no greater than its intrinsic width": unset the width (no `width` property in cascade, `width: auto` or `width: unset`) and set `max-width` to `50%`.